# c++ создание функции для заполнения структуры значениями (упражнение С.Прата)

Tags: c++, функции

в задании нужно дать определения и написать объявления трех функций, причем первая из них должна быть именно как в комментарии. остальное, в т.ч. все в main(), было дано.
моя ф-я set написана по-другому. не понимаю, зачем выделять еще один блок памяти под переменные-члены структуры. ведь если структура создается, но не инициализируется, память под переменные все равно выделяется, так? мой код, по идее, работает согласно с заданием. объясните, пожалуйста, что имеет в виду автор учебника.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct Stringy
{
    char * str;
    int ct; //длина str без \0
};

void set(Stringy& beany, char * line);
//по условию: должна выделить пространство для хранения строки
//использовать переменную типа str структуры как указатель на новый блок
//скопировать строку в этот новый блок
//создать элемент ct 

void show(const Stringy& beany, int number = 1);
void show(const char * line, int number = 1);

int main()
{
    Stringy beany;
    char testing[] = "Reality is f***ing dreadful.";
    set(beany, testing);
    show(beany);
    show(beany, 2);
    testing[0] = 'D';
    testing[1] = 'u';
    show(testing);
    show(testing, 3);

    return 0;
}

void set(Stringy& beany, char * line)
{
    beany.str = line;
    beany.ct = strlen(line);
}

void show(const char * line, int number)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void show(const Stringy& beany, int number)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        cout << beany.str << endl;
        //cout << beany.ct << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

АПД: ага, я же тут просто указателю str присваиваю адрес line, поняла. и переписала функцию вот так.

```
void set(Stringy& beany, char * line)
{
    beany.str = new char[strlen(line) + 1];
    strcpy(beany.str, line);
    beany.ct = strlen(beany.str);
}
```

Comment: Единственное, что я бы добавил - проверку аргумента `line` на равенство `nullptr`.

Comment: @Harry главное потом не начать добавлять эти проверки на каждое использование указателя. Мое мнение - за валидность аргументов должен отвечать тот, кто вызывает функцию.

Comment: Не очень хорошо бегать по строке три раза подряд (strlen, strcpy, strlen). line должен быть 'const char*', set - членом (а то и вовсе конструктором) Stringy, ну и проверку, что не затираем уже существующую строку надо, а то будут утечки.

Comment: @alexolut И в самом деле, дурака сваляли в комитете, проверяя в `delete` указатель на равенство нулю... :) Что до проверок старой строки - то в данном коде вообще проблема: отсутствие инициализации `beany` в `main` (а этот код **дан** в учебнике, кстати, как и сигнатура `set` без `const`), так что проверять, не затрем ли что - дело гиблое. А так, конечно, можно просто написать `strcpy((beany.str = new char[(beany.ct = strlen(line))+1]),line)`. Но не в учебном же задании :)

Comment: @Harry `delete` - особый случай. Посмотрите лучше на конструктор `std::string` и прочие сишные функции типа `strcpy`, которые требуют от аргументов быть не `nullptr`.

Comment: @Harry а что не так в этой строке? По-моему всё вполне нормально выглядит, ну если исключение от `new` не ловить/проверять `0` конечно...

Comment: @pavel В какой?

Comment: @Harry `strcpy((beany.str = new char[(beany.ct = strlen(line))+1]),line)`

Comment: @pavel Почему не так? Я написал, что можно даже так, в одну строку :) Просто не самый понятный стиль для начинающего.